# How to store data to browser cache directory in html?

Tags: html, forms, jscript

The Project: https://github.com/marcosnunes/storeData

I need to publish into {div id="result"}{/div} the data from the form and then store to local cached directory. Would anyone help me to write this code? What I am trying to do is make a local site for to be loaded into an Android Hibrid App.

The form:

```
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
<div class="w3-card-4" style="width:100%">
<header class="w3-container w3-light-grey">
<h2><Div id="nameBox"></Div></h2>
</header>
<div class="w3-container">
<h2><div id="result"></div></h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<h3>Adicionar um Envelope e Saldo</h3>

<form name="contact-form" 
method="post" id="contact-form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputName">Envelope</label>
<input type="text" 
class="form-control" id="cardName" name="cardName" placeholder="Envelope" 
required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputValue">Valor</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="Value" name="Value" 
placeholder="Valor" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputDescription">Descrição</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Description" 
name="Description" 
placeholder="Descrição" required>
</div>

<button onclick="store()" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" 
value="Submit" 
id="submit_form">Adicionar</button>

</form> 
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need too create new div on the button onclick()

The java code

```
<script>

function store(){
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {  
        var inputName = document.getElementById("cardName");
        sessionStorage.setItem("cardName", inputName.value);

        var inputValue = document.getElementById("Value");
        sessionStorage.setItem("Value", inputValue.value);

        var inputDescription = document.getElementById("Description");
        sessionStorage.setItem("Description", inputDescription.value);

        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("cardName");
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("Value");
        document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("Description");

        } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Ops! Alguma coisa deu errado...";
    }
}
```

Comment: Directory or MySQL? You said you wanted to write a web service, but what server are you using to do that?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, we help with written code, and users posting questions are supposed to make a proper research and an effort of their own, which you obviously haven't, providing a [_sample within the question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do and come back with it, if you can't make it work. If anything is unclear, please reread [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I got it !
Just inserted type="button" on button.

```
<button onclick="store()" **type="button"** class="btn btn-primary" 
name="submit" value="Submit" 
id="submit_form">Adicionar</button>
```